# Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use | creates user in database but give this error

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to sign a user up to my application, when I do so it gives me the error in the console of `Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use` but I do have passport initialized. It does create the user in the database correctly though. It just seems like the initial passport setup is wrong.

I have included what I think are the important parts of the application to explain what is happening. I included a comment down at the line that the stack trace points to.

**App.js**

```
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    // create new redis store.
    store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client, auto_reconnect: true}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60 * 1000 * 60 * 24 * 30 // 30 days
    },
}));

// PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
require('./controllers/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routes
require('./routes/index.js')(app, passport);
```

**controllers/passport.js**

```
passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'email',
      passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, existingUser) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          if (existingUser) {
            req.flash('form', {
              email: req.body.email
            });
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'An account with that email address already exists.'));
          }

          var user = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password 
          });

          user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return done(err, false, req.flash('error', 'Error saving user.'));

            var token = new Token({ _userId: user._id, token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
            token.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return done(null, false, req.flash('error', err.message));
            var email = req.body.email;
            // Send the email for the token
            var message = 'Hello,\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp:\/\/' + req.headers.host + '\/confirmation\/' + token.token + '\/' + email + '\n';
            sendEmail('"APPNme" noreply@example.com', user.email, 'Account Verification Token', message);
            });
            var time = 14 * 24 * 3600000;
            req.session.cookie.maxAge = time; //2 weeks
            req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + time);
            req.session.touch();
            return done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '.')); // stack trace points to this line as the error line. 
          });
        });

    })
  );
```

**routes/index.js**

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', section
    failureRedirect : '/signup',
    failureFlash : true 
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `passport.initialize` middleware.
Refer: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

```
// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
```

The order needs to be maintained:

**Docs**

- bodyParser
- express session
- require passport.js
- passport.initialize
- passport.session
- require routes

Comment: I thought I had that guess not. I tried adding it just after I required passport in my app.js file but that doesn't seem to work, exact same error. Where should it be going?

Comment: out of order middleware is problematic for passport. Use the order exactly from the docs. 
1) express session, 2) initialize 3) passport session

Comment: I do have it in that order. If you look at my app.js file in the OP you will see where I have put the passport init/session

Comment: Got it working, you were right on the order being finicky. I moved some stuff around and it works now. TY

Comment: add the configuration before everything. 1) require 2) passport config 3)cookieparse ..etc

Comment: Edit my answer with the order that you used. I will approve it